# Google Cloud Functions: How to add <PROJECT_ID>.getIamPolicy permission to a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

When trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function with a Pub/Sub topic trigger, using this command:

`gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> --runtime=ruby27 --entry-point=<FUNCTION_ENTRY_POINT> --region=us-east1 --source=. --trigger-topic=<PUBSUB_TOPIC_NAME> --gen2`

I'm getting this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) User [<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>] does not have permission to access projects instance [<PROJECT_ID>:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission`

I can't figure out how to grant the correct permission or role to the service account. I've given it "security Reviewer", which seems like it would cover `getIamPolicy`, judging by its description:

> Security reviewer role, with permissions to get any IAM policy.

What am I getting wrong here?

I've tried adding the 'Security Reviewer' role, with various principals, including the runtime accounts, and my own account. I've also tried the `Service Account User` role.

Comment: Clarifying question: Did you already create the PubSub topic as described in this tutorial? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#functions-deploy-command-ruby

Comment: I did already create the PubSub topic, yes. But I realized my error; trying to add roles in the wrong Console panel.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I was trying to add these roles in the wrong place. I was in Console > IAM & Admin > Service Accounts, while I should have been in Console > IAM & Admin > IAM, and adding roles in the table found there. Once I added the "Security Reviewer" role there, the errors went away.